# Are the generalized zeroes of an analytic function necessarily isolated?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series, examples-counterexamples

The zeroes of any non-zero analytic function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are isolated. By a *generalized zero* of a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, let us mean a zero of $f^{(n)}$ for some natural number $n \in \{0,1,2\ldots\}$.

> Are the generalized zeroes of a non-polynomial analytic function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ necessarily isolated?

My guess is 'no', but if the answer is yes, I'm also interested in the complex case where $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: For complex analytic functions, the zeroes are indeed isolated.

Comment: @Bernard, what i mean is, are the generalized zeroes necessarily isolated?

Comment: The derivative of an analytic function is analytic, so the generalised zeroes are  ‘ordinary’  zeroes of an analytic function.

Comment: @Bernard I think you don't get the point. We call $z$ a generalized zero if it is a zero of $f^{(n)}$ for _some_ $n$. So, sure there a no zeros of $f^{(n)}$ arbitrary close to $z$ (unless $f$ is a polynomial), but there might be generalized zeros arbitrary close to $z$. I don't know who downvoted this interesting question. Upvote from me.

Comment: @amsmath: It seems I misunderstood the question. Anyway, it's not me who downvoted (I *never* downvote), and I'll upvote at once I agree with you, it's an interesrting question

Comment: @Bernard I appreciate your reaction!

Comment: @goblin You should exclude polynomials from your considered functions.

Comment: @amsmath, thanks!

Comment: Let  $f(z) = \frac{z}{1-z^2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^{2k}$. Since $a_k$ is arbitrary small then $f^{(2k)}(z)$ has a zero arbitrary close to $z=0$.

Comment: @reuns Guessing from what you have written, I think you mean $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ with $a_{2k}$ chosen arbitrarily small. How can you infer that there are generalized zeros of $f$ arbitrarily close to zero?

Comment: @amsmath Once the $a_{2k+1} \ne 0$ are fixed, you are free to choose $a_{2k}$ arbitrary small, thus to set $z_{2k}$ the zero of $f^{(2k)}(z)$ arbitrary close to $z=0$, and clearly $z_{2k}$ doesn't depend much on $a_{2m},m > k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f(z) = \frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}- \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{((2k)!)^2} z^{2k}$$
It is not hard to see there is a sequence $z_k\sim \frac{1}{(2k)!} \to 0$ such that $f^{(2k)}(z_k) = 0$

Comment: This is a very nice construction. It works!